# XCode 4.5 Documentation Screen obscures main project screen

Tags: xcode

I am using xCode for the first time - since 1986 I've used other IDE's (turboPascal, JBuilder, Eclipse, NetBeans, Tibco BW...) but to the uninitiated Xcode seems reach new levels of awkwardness.

Every time I access help e.g 'API documentation help'  the documentation screen obscures all other windows.   Presumably there is a magic key that dismisses the documentation screen and return me to the main project screen. (Like a back button in a browser).  I've tried many key combinations.

Is there a magic key that always gets you back 'as you were'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a shortcut to switch between the windows of the active app in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts. I prefer <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This will allow you to switch between the documentation and the editor window with a shortcut. You could also use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the documentation window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **command + ~**  to alternate between views, this works in every app on macosx.